# Store multiple contacts in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am using below code to save contacts in device using phonegap. I want to perform certain action after all contacts saved successfully. But save() method is asynchronous so i can't able to know when all contacts are saved.

Is it possible without making change in save() method?

If not then, What changes are required in save() method?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < allContacts.length; i++) {
             var obj = eval(allContacts[i]);
             var contact = navigator.contacts.create(obj);
             contact.save();
     }
```

Thanks in advance
Yogesh Patel

I made change on above code

I have written code for restore multiple contacts in Iphone with Phonegap. And i want to perform certain action after all contacts restore successfull. Its working fine if no of contacts is near about 400 if i increase no of contacts near about 1000 then its skip some(10 to 15) of the contacts. Each time when i restore i get different no of skip contacts. And for the skip contacts fail() function is not called. What should i do next? I need to change save method in cordova js?

Below is my code:

```
function storeContacttodevice(json1,callback) {
    var temp=0;
    var json2 = json1.split(';');
     for(var kl=0;kl<json2.length;kl++){
           var jsonparsecontact=JSON.parse(json2[kl]);
           var myContact = navigator.contacts.create(jsonparsecontact);
           myContact.save(function onSuccess(contact){
                        var mssg="Restoring contacts to your device  " + temp + "  Out  
                                  Of  " + json2.length;
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg( "b",  mssg, false );
                       if(temp == json2.length - 1) {
                            return callback();
                        }
                        temp++;
                        } ,
                        function onError(contactError){
                          alert("Error in saving contacts");
                          return callback();
                        }
                        );       
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance
Yogesh Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use counters to know when all contacts are saved:

```
function onSuccess(contact) {
    this.successCount = this.successCount + 1;
    if (this.contactNumber == this.successCount + this.errorCount) {
        // You know that all contacts have been saved
    }
};
function onError(contactError) {
    this.errorCount = this.errorCount + 1;
    if (this.contactNumber == this.successCount + this.errorCount) {
        // You know that all contacts have been saved
    }
};
...
...
// In your function saving the contacts
this.successCount = 0;
this.errorCount = 0;
this.contactNumber = allContacts.length;
for(var i = 0; i < allContacts.length; i++) {
    var obj = eval(allContacts[i]);
    var contact = navigator.contacts.create(obj);
    contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

I hope this solution will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,    I tried in this way its work fine if no of contacts is near about 400, if i increased no of contacts to 1000 then some of (near about 10 to 15) are skipped, and skiped no of contacts are different in  each  restore time. I mean fail function is not called if  some contacts is not restored?